# How do I get my text to continiously change based on the result of a httprequest until end condition is met?

Tags: angularjs

I am a bit of an angular newbie. I basically need to update a piece of text with progress information until a task has completed. I want to do this by having angular request the update text every 5 seconds.

My resource call looks like this:

```
getPublishProgress: function () {
            return $http.get("backoffice/Approval/ApprovalApi/GetPublishProgress");
        }
```

In my controller I can do it once, like this:

```
awaitingResource.getPublishProgress().then(function (response) { $scope.publishProgress = response.data });
```

So what I want to do is run that code in my controller every 5 seconds without locking up the page (the message will have specific text to indicate that the polling should be stopped).

How do I do this with Angular.Js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think everything you need here - is to figure out how to implement long poll request in angularJS. Here is [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rishabh/Kuewm/).

```
$scope.publishProgress = "";
var poll = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        awaitingResource.getPublishProgress().then(function (response) { 
           $scope.publishProgress = response.data
        });
        poll();
    }, 5000);
};     
poll();
```

If you will need additional information, leave a comment. Hope it will help you!

Comment: Hey Mikki, thanks for the reply! When Poll() is run will that not prevent any code following Poll() from being run? there are other things happening in the same controller

Comment: @Comanighttrain  yes, sir , timeout and interval are async functions

Comment: I'll give it a shot ASAP and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: Worked a treat - added a stop condition like this:

                if (response.data === "Finished")
                {
                    $scope.publishLocked = false;
                    $scope.publishButtonText = "Publish Selected";
                    $scope.publishProgress = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    poll();
                }
            }, 5000);
        };